# SQL pivot function in VBA

Tags: sql, vba, excel, pivot

[SQL pivot function text file database with VBA Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38400218/sql-pivot-function-text-file-database-with-vba-excel)

Dear Expert, I have an query i.e **SQL pivot function text file database with VBA Excel** which i will able to resolved with above link query and the correct answer.

I requesting your help, please guide what value's should be provide to function i.e.

```
Public Function getData(db1 As String, db2 As String, var1 As String, var2 As String) As ADODB.Recordset
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL?

Comment: @jarlh No it executing via VBA Excel, the same question i am referring via mention link just to know the value need to be provide to mentioned function.

Comment: Then you can remove the mysql tag.