# Summing csv columns

Tags: excel, csv

I have a csv file with a couple columns and about 100k rows. One of the columns is a date, and I was wondering what the easiest way was to count the number of rows that have a certain date for all the possible dates and make a new csv file with just the date and the number of rows that have that date in the specific column. Any language or method is fine!

Thanks

[Example of what data looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXVcs.png)

Comment: You could use a pivot table for this.  If you want a programming solution then it would be best to provide some code you already tried and describe what problem you had with it.

Comment: @TimWilliams Hi! I addede a picture of what the table looks like now, there are hundreds of dates over 100,000 rows so I can't manually do a sum+if combo for each date. I rarely do data management, but I want to do this to speed up my queries

Comment: What's wrong with using a pivot table?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38400218/sql-pivot-function-text-file-database-with-vba-excel shows how to query a text file using ADO - you can use something like `select date_field, count(epsilon_id) as num from [filename] group by date_field` and then save the results to csv

Comment: You can open a CSV and work with it just like you would an Excel workbook (except without formatting).  The number of rows is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) and Visual Studio in C#. This is by far the easiest as well as a fast way to read and process CSV files. CsvHelper is a popular library that makes it easy to process most any CSV files and is much faster than the standard .NET alternatives.

Here is another blog about using the class. [Keep it Simple with CvsHelper](http://renanayacobi.blogspot.com/2012/01/csvhelper.html)